# How to place an icon in the navigation bar section in navigation pages

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

all the pages my app  is  navigation page . I wanted to know how to put an icon on all  pages and in the  navigation bar section ?

I want to write the code once and apply it to all pages.

Because when I enter the nested pages, icon disappears!

Thanks in advance to those who help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add an icon to the toolbar in the Android app project.

[image]

The default layout for the toolbar in a new template Forms app is:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
android:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" >

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Add an icon to this:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
android:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" >
<ImageView
    android:src="@drawable/star_small"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

**Updated:**

Set id for the imageview in Toolbar.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
android:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" >
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:src="@drawable/star_small"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Add the code in MainActivity after `LoadApplication(new App());`.

```
 var imageview = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.imageView1);
        imageview.Click += delegate
        {
            Console.WriteLine("start clicked!");
        };
```

> How can I enter HorizontalOptions="End" in the Toolbaritem.xml? I want to go to the right side of the page!

Add the code below in ImageView.

```
android:layout_gravity="end"
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to add a click feature and change its color? @Wendy Zang - MSFT

Comment: @hoh The code i provided could work for all the pages and you could add a click feature for this. Any update for this case?

Comment: How can I enter HorizontalOptions="End" in the Toolbar.xml? I want icon go to the right side of the page! @Wendy Zang - MSFT

Comment: I have updated my reply. Please check it.

Answer (score 1):

Just use in your page:

```
<ContentPage
    NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="True"
    NavigationPage.HasBackButton="False">

    <NavigationPage.TitleView>
        <Image />
    </NavigationPage.TitleView>


 YOUR VIEW

</ContentPage>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Is it possible to hit this code once and apply it on all pages?( For example, on the App.xaml or App.xaml.cs). @piotruspan

Comment: Unfortunately not